# How to make browser not to refresh full page when it goes to URL?

Tags: php, javascript, html, url, browser

I tried to understand - is it any method to ask browser not to refresh entire page when user clicks onto . Hash adding method is seen - I need another method, working with links without hashes.
May be any headers should be sent ? Or something another ?

I want to process GET queries returning only the part of HTML (or special js commands), not all page, and process it in AJAX-style.

Comment: Do you have any experience with Javascript or AJAX? Your question isn't very clear, but try learning about AJAX, and then try writing something on your own. If you're having a specific issue with what your code, post a new question about it, and we can help you much better then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ajaxify your links through jquery. Something like this:

```
$('a.ajax').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var target=$(this).attr('data-target');
    var url=$(this).attr('href');
    $(target).load(url+' '+target);
}
```

This can be used in conduction with the following HTML:

```
<div id="output">
 Hello <a href="world.html" class="ajax" data-target="#output">World</a>
<div>
```

and inside world.html you would need to have:

```
<div id="output">
  Foo bar baz boo
</div>
```

In theory this should load content of the dif from "world" file into the div inside the first file, but I haven't tried it. I think it's what you need, because the regular link is still there, google will properly index this bypassing ajax and your users will be happy to see part of the page change.

Answer (score 1):

you could make it 'fake' links doing something like this:

```
<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="loadPage('mypagename');">My Link</span>
```

The function then would be:

```
function loadPage(pageName){
    // do ajax call here using pageName var
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent navigation when a user clicks a hyperlink with a URL.  Using a hash value to navigate or having your hyperlinks invoke JavaScript is generally the way to add navigation inside of a single page.

However, if you're trying to *convert* an existing page that's not designed this way, you would have to use JavaScript to modify hyperlinks so they invoke Ajax.  For example:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

    var oldUrl = links[i].getAttribute('href');
    links[i].setAttribute('href', 'javascript:void(0)');

    links[i].onclick = (function(url) {
        return function() {
            // Then you can do your AJAX code here
        }
    })(oldUrl);
}
```

I recommend that you don't do something like this, though, and rather create your page with an AJAX design in mind.

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing. You say, "You cannot prevent navigation when a user clicks a hyperlink with a URL", then proceed to describe how to do so. I also disagree about creating the page with AJAX in mind. It's called progressive enhancement. Design the page for the lowest common denominator and then apply AJAX behavior on top of that... unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: My answer shows how to make the hyperlink so it no-longer contains a URL, so the "you cannot prevent navigation" statement is correct.  The reason I stand by designing with AJAX in mind is that although you could retrieve the page via AJAX and do selective replacements, the URL you request will still return the entire HTML document, so you don't make your site perform any differently or better.

Comment: You can override the browsers behavior by binding a click event to the link and returning `false` from the event handler **without** removing the url.

Comment: True, as long as JavaScript is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the url without using hashes can be achieved with the Html5 History API: http://html5demos.com/history

Not supported by older browser though, so you must always have a fallback.